# Почему в исходящих почтового сервера нет, отправленного скриптом, письма?

Tags: python-3.x, email, smtplib

Используемый скрипт:

```
import config

# typical values for text_subtype are plain, html, xml
text_subtype = 'plain'

from email.mime.text import MIMEText
msg = MIMEText(text, text_subtype)
msg['Subject'] = subject
msg['From'] = config.sender
msg['To'] = config.to_email
msg['Cc'] = ', '.join(config.to_cc_emails)

from smtplib import SMTP
with SMTP(config.smtp_server) as smtp:
    smtp.set_debuglevel(config.debug_smtp)
    smtp.starttls()
    smtp.login(config.username, config.password)
    smtp.send_message(msg)
```

Тестировал на mail.ru и корпоративной почте.
Просто, если отправлять письмо через клиент или вебстраницу почты, то письмо в отправленных есть.

Подскажите, как отправлять скриптом письмо и увидеть его в папке исходящих.

**update.**
Можно костыльно обойти проблему если отправлять от gmail -- он автоматически добавит письмо в папку отправленных писем.

Comment: вы механизм работы почты понимаете? Через веб инструментами почтового сервиса письмо попадает в исходящие. Только так и никак иначе. И доступа такого извне нет и быть не может

Comment: Если бы понимал, не задавал такие вопросы :)

Comment: это клиента (apple,thunderbird), от сервиса (mail.ru, gmail), от протокола зависит (SMTP, IMAP). Большинство сервисов должны IMAP поддерживать (тогда только названия папок (типа Gmail/Sent) под разные сервисы и возможно ещё пару настроек нужно, чтобы новый сервис начать поддерживать). [Move an email in GMail with Python and imaplib](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3527933/4279)

Comment: @jfs, в вики написано что хоть IMAP может отправлять письма, его команда APPEND "считается «неудачной» и «небезопасной»", поэтому для отправки используется SMTP, но почему она такой считается? В англ версии этой статьи упоминание APPEND вообще нет